# Repair APFS Container - Physical store disk listed under wrong APFS container reference

Tags: disk-utility, apfs

High level - have an APFS container that won't mount or repair. In Disk Utility I have the external drive (disk3) with the "APFS Physical Store" unmounted below. (disk3s2).  I then have a mystery drive listed "AppleAPFSMedia" (uninitialized) which lists as (disk4).  Running "diskutil apfs list" in terminal turns up the following which is listing disk3s2 under disk4.  My thought is that the references got messed up somehow. Any thoughts on how to fix this (aside from the obvious, format and start over).

+-- Container ERROR -69808

```
======================
APFS Container Reference:     disk4
Size (Capacity Ceiling):      ERROR -69620
Capacity In Use By Volumes:   ERROR -69524
Capacity Not Allocated:       ERROR -69524
|
+-< Physical Store disk3s2 6810D19F-3ECC-458A-B11A-E65613D4A410
|   -----------------------------------------------------------
|   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk3s2
|   Size:                       4000577273856 B (4.0 TB)
|
+-> No Volumes
```

Comment: Assuming you twiddle the bit needed to get a mount, how do you have any confidence only that one bit failed? Whiteout the backstory how this became corrupted, wipe and start over is the correct choice. Is this really an attempt to do data recovery since there isn’t a recent backup?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Its more out of curiosity about how APFS works in general and what might be a repair issue.  I found a similar question on apple without any answers: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8334337 iboysoft is able to see the APFS partitions inside the container, so I can recover data that way if I decide to.